# Block a client without blocking others in Select

Tags: c, select, client, server

I have to create a program with two parts : Client / Server.

I receive commands from different clients and I want to put the client waiting during the command is executed, but, the other clients must be able to send command to the server

e.g :
C1 (for client 1) and C2 (for client 2)

C1 send command -> server receive it and execute it and he can't accept command from C1 for x seconds but he can accept command from the C2.

How can I do it with select function withous threads.

This is my current code from the server :

```
void            client_ask(t_listplayer *list, t_network *net) {
  char          *buffer = xmalloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
  int           rd = 0;

  memset(buffer, 0, 200);
  while (list != NULL) {
      if (FD_ISSET(list->player->fd, &net->readfds)) {
          if ((rd = xread(list->player->fd, buffer, 200)) > 0) {
              buffer[rd - 1] = '\0';
              printf("Client n°: %d asking : [%s]\n", list->player->fd, buffer);
              sleep(3); // This one put all the server in waiting
              memset(buffer, 0, 200);
            } else {
              close(list->player->fd);
              printf("Client n°: %d has just disconnected", list->player->fd);
            }
        }
      list = list->next;
    }
}
```

So, I've make many research .. I've heard things about timeout but i don't know how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes of course, sorry i'm new .. So i've put a little code to explain more

Comment: It's ok to be new ;)

Comment: I would swear I know what school project you're currently working on just by looking at your code XD. This smells like epitech and the zappy project

Comment: didn't have 20 reputations ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manage client-states in your list of clients. If the client state is 'wait', do not answer it (or better : answer "you must wait for x" or some useful feedback). All the clients will be able to send requests and only the one in the correct states will be processed.

Do not forget to reset the client's state when your work is done on its request.